# iOS 11.0 UITextField secureTextEntry doesn't work?

Tags: ios, uitextfield, ios11

I found that `secureTextEntry` doesn't work on iOS 11.0, my code is simple like this:

```
tfPwd1.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
tfPwd1.secureTextEntry = YES;
tfPwd1.delegate = self;
```

What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you problem with iOS 11.0 only? Is this code works for other OS versions?

Comment: this code work fine for other versions, just after I update to iOS 11.0...

Answer (score 1):

change `.secureTextEntry`  to `.isSecureTextEntry`

hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

I just check on my system its working with this code

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        txtfld.isSecureTextEntry = true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you call `[tfPwd1 becomeFirstResponder]` anywhere? Add  `tfPwd1.secureTextEntry = YES;` before calling `[tfPwd1 becomeFirstResponder]`. Don't add it  while `UIKeyboard` is present

Comment: I add tfPwd1.secureTextEntry = YES where i init the textfield, the textfield is secure entry before I update to iOS 11.0. After I update, the "setSecureTextEntry" lose efficacy.